# Cannot find the correct Regex solution

Tags: regex

I have content that looks like this:

```
001 B OR 06K24b 01 TCP SC C 02
001 B CC 12K48b 99 BCP SC A 02 1982-11-09
001 B OR 06K24b 01 TCP SC C 02
```

I want my regex expression to match line 2 but not line 1 or 3.

I think what I need is a positive lookbehind but I'm unsure. Even if I'm correct, I can't figure out how to correctly apply it.

I have tried the following:

```
^(?<=([0-9]{3} [A-Z] [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{2} [A-Z] [0-9]{2})).*
```

and Positive Lookahead:

```
^(?!([0-9]{3} [A-Z] [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{2} [A-Z] [0-9]{2}))$
```

Please guide me to the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As line 2 ends with what looks like a date, then you can try the following regex:

```
^.+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
```

It tests that a line ends with four digits followed by a dash, two digits, a dash and two digits.

Answer (score 0):

This regex, re-utilized the most of your regex:

```
^[0-9]{3} [A-Z] [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{2} [A-Z] [0-9]{2} [0-9].*
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQCdlv/1)**

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[0-9]{3}` | any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times) |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[A-Z]` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[A-Z]{2}` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times) |
| ' ' | a space |
| `.` | any character except \n |
| `.` | any character except \n |
| `K` | K |
| `.` | any character except \n |
| `.` | any character except \n |
| `b` | 'b ' |
| `[0-9]{2}` | any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times) |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[A-Z]{3}` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (3 times) |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[A-Z]{2}` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times) |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[A-Z]` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[0-9]{2}` | any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times) |
| ' ' | a space |
| `[0-9]` | any character of: '0' to '9' |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: Thanks for this. It appears I was overthinking the solution.

Comment: Absolutely. No need complicated regex

Comment: Feel free to upvote if it was helpful, even if not accepted answer... It's the way to thanks here